# Stokes's theorem outer unit normal for a hemisphere

Tags: surfaces, surface-integrals, stokes-theorem

Stokes's theorem says 
$$\oint \mathbf{F}.d\mathbf{r}=\iint_{D}^{-} \nabla \times \mathbf{F}\cdot \mathbf{n} \, dA$$

Evaluate using the RHS of Stokes' theorem the following problem.

for the hemisphere 
$$S:x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=9,$$
$$z\geq 0,$$ its bounding circle $$C:x^{2}+y^{2}=9,$$
$$z=0$$ and the field $$\mathbf{F}=y\mathbf{i}-x\mathbf{j}$$

I have no idea how to find the outer normal vector.

I have tried grad(F)/Magnitude of grad (F) but its incorrect

Comment: I believe there are three outer normal vectors, but the equation you wrote down is for Green's theorem, and it's not clear what you want to do.

Comment: I will edit the post. It was typed in haste.

Comment: @Nameless I want to find the normal vector

Comment: One needs to orient the boundary contour in order to determine the outward from inward normal.

Comment: my text gives me 
$$\mathbf{n}=\frac{x\mathbf{i}+y\mathbf{j}+z\mathbf{k}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}}$$.
Have zero idea where this comes from. It is very elusive.
@Dr.MV

Comment: @stoke's that is the unit vector of a vector, it takes in an arbitrary vector and turns it  into a unit vector or vector of length 1. Not to be confused with the normal vector which is a vector arbitrarily defined by the cross product of two vectors in the normal plane. It is arbitrary because the direction it points is determined by the order of the operands to the cross product which is not commutative.

Comment: Would it suffice for me to take the cross product of the 2 tangent vector?
The parametrisation can be done with only 1 variable, not 2. So this is another issue.

Comment: @marshalcraft That is the unit normal to the surface, not a plane, defined by $x^2+y^2+z^2=9$.  However, there are two unit normal vectors.  They are $\hat n=\pm \frac13(\hat xx+\hat yy+\hat zz)$.  The sign is chosen to conform with the right-hand rule.  The problem herein does not state, however, the orientation of the contour.

Comment: The order of the operands needs to follow some rule such as the right hand rule. Also consider what the differential $dA$ actually is.

Comment: @marshalcraft The only requirement here is to specify the orientation of the contour that bounds the hemispherical surface.  Once known, then the outward surface normal will be one of the radial unit vectors as written in the previous comment.

Comment: @Nameless I think traditionally there is confusion sometimes with the explicit names given to the special cases of the generalized fundamental theorem of calculus. I have even recalled one story that Stokes only ever used a case of it on an exam and had only heard about it in a letter from Lord Kelvin who in turn learned of it by acquiring an obscure publication written by Green himself. Also I believe there is differences in naming based on if it is an application in physics (electrodynamics) or mathematics. But I like to think Green came up with it so.

Answer (score 1):

Stokes theorem is basically relating the flux through a surface with a closed path around the surface. Intuitively it says that a vector field, the total flux of the surface or flow through the closed path, must be equal to the dot product of the vector field along the path.

$\iint \nabla \times \mathbf {\vec F}\cdot \mathbf n dA = \iint \nabla \times \mathbf{\vec F}(\mathbf G(u,v))\cdot (\frac{\partial{\mathbf G}}{\partial u}\times \frac{\partial {\mathbf G}}{\partial v})dudv$

One such parameterization $\mathbf G$ is $\mathbf G(\phi, \theta)$ in spherical coordinates. $\mathbf F(\phi, \theta)=\langle 3\sin\phi \sin \theta, -3\sin\phi \cos\theta, 0 \rangle $ this comes from cartesian coordinates in terms of spherical.

$\iint \nabla \times \mathbf {\vec F}\cdot \mathbf n dA = \iint \nabla \times \langle 3\sin\phi \sin \theta, -3\sin\phi \cos\theta, 0 \rangle \cdot \langle 3\cos\phi \sin\theta, 3\sin\phi \cos\theta, -3\sin\phi \rangle \times\langle -3\sin \phi \sin\theta, 3\sin\phi \cos\theta, 0 \rangle d\phi d\theta$

It should be strait forward how to integrate this, but you do need to consider the limit's of integration to fit what was asked. You should arrive at the same conclusion when you compute the line integral along the path and further it should be a little easier.

Comment: There may be easier ways by taking advantage of symmetry as Dr. MV noted the surface normal points in the same direction as the displacement vector for the coordinate that is contained in the osculating plane. So then you just need $dA$.

Comment: Solid answer +1 ... I do think it might be "overkill" for purpose here.